# Java: Why we need to cast a float but not a double?

Tags: java, casting, double

I don't know if you consider this an important question or not but I want to know.
float is a float number (4 bytes).
double is a float number (8 bytes).
Why we define double wihtout casting:

```
double d = 2.1;
```

But we need to cast with floats:

```
float f = (float) 2.1;
```

or

```
float f = 2.1f;
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A floating-point literal is of type float if it ends with the letter `F` or `f`; otherwise its type is `double` and it can optionally end with the letter `D` or `d`.

The floating point types (`float` and `double`) can also be expressed using E or e (for scientific notation), `F` or `f` (32-bit float literal) and `D` or `d` (64-bit double literal; this is the default and by convention is omitted).

```
double d1 = 123.4;
// same value as d1, but in scientific notation
double d2 = 1.234e2;
float f1  = 123.4f;
```

[See Floating-Point Literals in oracle Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Answer (score 4):

By default, Java compiler perceives 2.1 as being a double (64 bits) and not as a float (32 bits). Declaring float f=2.1 would result in loss of precision. Hence, Java forces you to do the casting to make sure you are declaring a float variable.

Without casting, you can achieve the same with the letter 'f' at the end of floating point numbers. For example, `float f=2.1f`.

Now you might ask, why a cast isn't required while converting from a long to a float because the former uses more bits internally than the latter. The answer is Java needs no casting on a widening path - byte => short => int => long => float => double. 
(Left to right (a widening conversion) - cast is not required; 
Right to left (a narrowing conversion) - explicit cast is required)

Comment: Note while `float` is wider than `long` it can have a lot less precision.

Answer (score 2):

Doubles are more precise and the extra storage cost is almost always negligible. So in Java by default 2.1 is a double type. Now to convert double to float you need to cast while assigning double data to double type cast is not required.